# How to inject service into factory created object in Symfony

Tags: symfony

I have custom class `EmailNotifier` which is created inside a factory class `NotifierFactory`. I need to use the Mailer service inside the EmailNotifier. But how to inject the service inside? It can't be injected into constructor, because I'm creating the class in this way:

```
$emailNotifier = new EmailNotifier();
```

I tried to inject it in services.yaml

```
App\Service\Notifier\Notifiers\EmailNotifier:
 calls:
    - [setMailer, ['@mailer']]
```

but the method setMailer() is never called.

Comment: Are all notifiers singletons? How do you get the email notifier from your factory? As a general rule: if you create with `new`, you also have to set the dependencies. if emailnotifier is a singleton, provide it as a parameter to the factory (see https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/tags.html#reference-tagged-services, which would be *one* way to implement this, it's not a factory but a manager then ^^). if it's not a singleton, write a factory for emailnotifier. the in-between is really inconvenient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also can inject mailer to `NotifierFactory` constructor via service container and in your factory do something like this:

```
$emailNotifier = (new EmailNotifier())->setMailer($this->mailer);
```

Update: maybe useful in your case
https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/factories.html

Comment: But then the factory class has to know about all dependencies of all objects (notifiers), which it is creating. I thought it would be better to let each factory-created object (notifier) to manage its own dependencies.

Comment: But in your example below you dont need a factory pattern

Comment: Yes, it looks so. I was used to use the factory pattern to solve this kind of problem. But now, with this Symfony DI approach it doesn't seem to be the best solution (or I can't use it the right way).

Answer (score 1):

If I choose another approach, I can inject services to my "notifiers"

```
# Defining each notifier as a service, then pass another service inside (mailer here)
notifiers.email:
    public: true
    class: App\Service\Notifier\Notifiers\EmailNotifier
    calls:
        - [setMailer, ['@mailer']]

# Pass each notifier service inside the Notifier object, which replaces the factory class
App\Service\Notifier\Notifier:
    calls:
        - [setNotifierServices, ['@notifiers.email']]
```

Comment: that's about what I was going for with my comment. I think this is the right approach. this is or something similar.

Comment: You can basically consider the container to be a factory in this case.  But if you do want an explicit factory (perhaps you want more than one factory) then yes, the factory class will have to manage all the dependencies needed for whatever it is creating.  That is what factories do.  However, I just want to add that using setter injection is somewhat rare.  You might be over using it.